# Merge two identical object model class after JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json

C# and Newtonsoft.JSON

I've an object model class like this

```
class RolePerson
    {
        public NodeRolePerson[] Items { get; set; }
    }

class NodeRolePerson
{

    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string dateUva { get; set; }
    public bool delegated { get; set; }
    public NodeentityOrg entityOrg { get; set; }
    .....
    public string userUva { get; set; }
}
.........
```

Now i get data with

```
RolePerson myP1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RolePerson>(data1,settings);
RolePerson myP2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RolePerson>(data2,settings);
```

How can i have only one object with both myP1 and myP2 ?

I've tried with

```
List<RolePerson> trace;
trace.Add(myP1);
trace.Add(myP2);
```

but receive a compilation error 'local variable not assigned'.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Is adding them to a list what you *really* want to do? By saying "merge" it almost sounds like you want to have one `RolePerson` object.

Comment: Yes, i would have one RolePerson object, but also with solution proposal i can resolve, just i've to iterate items but the better solution is one RolePerson object. I choose "list way" only because i need to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    var items = new List<NodeRolePerson>(myP1.Items);

    items.AddRange(myP2.Items);

    RolePerson trace = new RolePerson { Items = items.ToArray() };
```

Answer (score 3):

You never actually created a new list:

```
List<RolePerson> trace = new List<RolePerson>();
trace.Add(myP1);
trace.Add(myP2);
```